# Need to use Graph API to get SharePoint site owners in Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, power-automate, flow, microsoft-graph

Need to use Graph API to get SharePoint site owners in Power Automate. Able to achieve it through REST API but not finding Graph API to fetch the SharePoint owners of the site.

Can you guide?

Comment: Is this is communication site or team site connected with M365 group?

Comment: Graph API calls you'll need: 1) Get your Site ID: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=YourSiteName`. 2) Get owners `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<<LOONG,ID,HERE>>/drive`

Comment: @GaneshSanap Its a Team site connected to M365 group. Looking for how can I compsoe it

Comment: In that case, you can get the M365 group owners for group associated with site using: [List group owners](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-owners?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If your SharePoint online site is connected to the Microsoft 365 group, it will be easier to fetch the owners using Microsoft graph API endpoints.

You can get the M365 group owners for the group associated with your SharePoint team site using List group owners endpoint like:

```
GET /groups/{id}/owners
```

**Example Response**:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-type: application/json

{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#directoryObjects",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
            "id": "4562bcc8-c436-4f95-b7c0-4f8ce89dca5e",
            "accountEnabled": true,
            "displayName": "MOD Administrator",
            "userPrincipalName": "admin@contoso.com"
        },
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
            "id": "f0206b06-7c5d-461c-ae24-08f68b7ef463",
            "accountEnabled": true,
            "displayName": "Megan Bowen",
            "userPrincipalName": "MeganB@contoso.com"
        },
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.user",
            "id": "5c70937c-d9ea-4a47-8852-ab77630f803d",
            "accountEnabled": true,
            "displayName": "Diego Siciliani",
            "userPrincipalName": "DiegoS@contoso.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Documentation**: [List group owners](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-owners?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, [Site resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/site?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) does not expose Owner property.

As a workaround, you could get the default library owner in the site. The default library owner would be the site owner. Below is the endpoint to get the sites drive, there is an owner property in the response:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drive`

Hope this helps. Best Wishes.